# How to get channel information from a global wire tap

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to use a `global wire tap` and still be able to log the identification information about the associated channel? To clarify lets suppose, I want to use a `global wire tap` as follows:

```
...
<int:channel id="myChannel1" />
...
<int:channel id="myChannel2" />
...

<int:wire-tap pattern="*" order="2" channel="wireTapChannel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter
   id="wireTapChannel"
   expression="'payload: ' + getPayload()"
   level="DEBUG"
   logger-name="WIRETAP" />
```

This would log something like

```
14:44:31,350 DEBUG WIRETAP:126 - payload: some payload1
14:44:31,350 DEBUG WIRETAP:126 - payload: some payload2
```

Now is there a way to put an expression so that looking into the logs I can identify the associated channels as well? I am expecting something like this:

```
14:44:31,350 DEBUG WIRETAP:126 - channel: myChannel1, payload: some payload1
14:44:31,350 DEBUG WIRETAP:126 - channel: myChannel2, payload: some payload2
```

Not sure whether this information is already lost once the flow reaches the wireTapChannel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable [Message History](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) and then use a Spel to print the desired headers.