# Correct configuration for global wire-tap

Tags: spring-integration

I am working with Spring Integration 4.3.9

I need use a `global wire-tap`

I have the following configuration:

```
<int:wire-tap pattern="*" 
              order="2" 
              channel="logger"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" 
                             level="INFO"
                             log-full-message="true"

                             /> 

<int:channel id="channel"
             datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" >
...
```

I don't know what is missing with the previous configuration. I can't see nothing special in the Console output about logging.

I did a research through the following links. 'Seems' all correct.

- [How to get channel information from a global wire tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108453/how-to-get-channel-information-from-a-global-wire-tap)
- [Global Wire Tap Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-global-wiretap)
- [spring-integration-5.0.xsd](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/config/spring-integration-5.0.xsd#L4284)

The app works fine, appears my own logging but nothing from the wire-tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bear in mind that by default `logging-channel-adapter` logs to the `org.springframework.integration.handler` category. So, if that one isn't switched on for the provided `INFO` level, you should do that.

Or supply `logger-name` for that `INFO` level.

Comment: Works, I've used the second approach. Thank you.